# Console log data from synchronous AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can't quite get my head around this. I'm trying to store the data from a synchronous ajax call in a var and console log this, however, the final console log is running before the synchronous call has finished so is returning `undefined`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var longitude = 51.4543,
      latitude = 0.9781,
      apiKey = "",
      result;

  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey + "/" + longitude + "," + latitude,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      result = data;
      //working
      console.log(result);
    },
  });
  //not working
  console.log(result);
});
```

I was under the impression that JS will wait for a synchronous call to finish before moving on, but I'm guessing that isn't the case? If not, how can I store the get response in a global var for use elsewhere?

Comment: synchronous ajax call has been deprecated, use success callback to do all logic

Comment: -@OP, You know it all... What is the question ?

Comment: @TomBarton, How about using `callback` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a JSONP request. JSONP **cannot** be performed synchronously. Consequently, `async: false` is ignored.

You have to restructure your code to work asynchronously.

Use a promise if you need to return something that other functions can use to get at the data. `$.ajax` will return one.

```
global_var = $.ajax(...);
global_var.done(function (data) { console.log("Use some data", data); });
global_var.done(function (data) { console.log("Use some data again", data); });
```

Answer (score 1):

So the short answer is **no**, you can't store `result` in a global variable. Whatever other function want's to use `result` needs to go inside this block:

```
function(data){
...here...
}
```